# MySql Average and Group By Usage

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Report Table

```
+----+-------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | mac_address       |quantity| zaman               |
+----+-------------------+--------+---------------------+
| 12 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-8C |   001  | 2017-12-07 10:22:09 |
| 14 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-8C |   001  | 2017-12-07 10:28:44 |
| 15 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-8D |   001  | 2017-12-07 10:44:54 |
| 19 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-AC |   001  | 2017-12-08 10:11:00 |
| 20 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-AD |   002  | 2017-12-08 10:32:12 |
| 24 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-8D |   001  | 2017-12-09 10:29:54 |
| 25 | 26-C0-B7-1E-7A-8E |   002  | 2017-12-09 10:39:11 |
```

I want to find average of quantity between days according to this equation:

```
Sum of quantity(9)/Number of day(3) = 3
```

---

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(quantity),2) AS quantity, DATE(zaman) as DateOnly 
FROM report WHERE DATE(zaman) BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY DateOnly
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: And what is the problem using that query ?

Comment: Result is wrong but I don't know yet what is the problem.

Comment: It's weird. I can't see the correct result

Comment: What if you removed the Dec.8 entries?  Would number-of-days still be 3?  Or would it drop to 2 (number-of-distinct-days)?

Comment: Perhaps the [window functions in MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions-overview/) would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using  sum  of the quantity  divided  by number of days

```
select sum(quantity) /( datediff(max(zaman), min(zaman))) as quantity 

FROM report WHERE DATE(zaman) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' error occur while using this query. I guess there is no result. But I'm sure there are records between days that I picked. Why could it be?

Comment: answer  update ..  removed  the  DATE(zaman) as DateOnly  because you are on a range of data

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ROUND((SUM(Quantity)*1.0)/datediff(MAX(Zaman), MIN(Zaman)),0)
FROM report 
WHERE zaman BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: It didn't work at the first place but I added 'AS quantity' after selection and it worked. Thank you for your time.